# How can I fetch all the Subscriptions/Users of an API in WSO2 APIM 2.1

Tags: rest, api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am aware that WSO2 APIM has its REST APIs which can fetch all the subscriptions and applications for an API. But since these REST APIs are scope specific and require scoped tokens which are created based on a particular users credentials it can only retrieve the subscriptions and applications of a particular user and not all the API subscriptions (subscriptions done by other users).
Is there any way I could retrieve all the subscriptions of an API (not restricted by a single user)

Answer (score 0):

Try explore the **Registry REST API** [1], I think this is the best way to get this generic information.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Using+the+Registry+REST+API

Another possibility is you check in the **Administration Services** [2] if you find something that can help you.

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/WSO2+Admin+Services

Comment: Thanks @Vitor Darela, I managed to find the answer which I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured out what I was doing wrong. The Store REST APIs are scoped and can only fetch the subscriptions of a particular user since the token scope is user specific. However, if I tried the Publishers REST API for fetching all subscriptions, I could fetch all the subscriptions regardless of the user and application, hence giving me the result I required.

Basically I used https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#SubscriptionCollection#subscriptionsGet

instead of 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/#!/operations#SubscriptionCollection#subscriptionsGet